# Is it good to include all the user details in the session in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently doing a code-igniter project and its based on student management system.I stored user id as

> $session_id = $this->session->userdata('u_id');

I'm planning to use a model function and get the other details of the currently logged user through this session_id.I'm using mysql as the database.my web application will used by more than 20,000 users.
Is there a performance difference in calling a model function everywhere when compared to declaring all the user details in the session array in codeigniter?

Comment: Why not build both solutions and then use CI's built in profiler to see which is actually the quickest?

Comment: If there is any data which you need all over the page; you can store in session. but calling it through model is best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems different from what I read in the title so I will awnser both.

Is it good to include all the user details in the session in codeigniter?:

No, it's not good to hold all the user data in a session. Only hold data that is neccecary to hold on to (Such as just a user ID would be enough), though in my personal opinion I'd also encrypt the data. Just for safety's sake.

Besides that, there is nothing wrong with calling a function to grab all the other data. It's what you'd need to do. You don't want your users to hold all their own data for no reason.

Comment: thanks @killstreet.
Nevertheless I want to include a header file in almost all views. Therefore i must to use the same model function in every controller, if i'm not using session for hold every detail. I actually want know the performance difference between above two.

Comment: @Sawan that is what a core controller is used for. You would be loading the model in the core controller and make sure your controllers extend the core.

Comment: Thanks @killstreet. I'll try it.